# Make img thumbnail gallary to work in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I insert some `php` code to make this dynamic. The problem becomes that when the website refreshes there i cant get to have a image preselected. How can I make that when I refresh the site a img is from UL is preselected.

**Html:**

```
<html>
    <div>
<div class="Vareside">
        <div class="Venstredel">
            <div class="Bildeholder">
                <img src="Bilder/1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
<div class="ProduktBilder">
            <ul class="p_ul">
                <li class="p_li"><img src="Bilder/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li class="p_li"><img src="Bilder/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li class="p_li"><img src="Bilder/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li class="p_li"><img src="Bilder/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
</div>
</html>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("ul li img").click(function(){
            var CurrentImageURL = $(this).attr("src");
            $(".Bildeholder img").attr("src", CurrentImageURL)
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: is this for work or school?

Comment: How do you "select" an image? By adding a class to the clicked image?

Comment: The clicked img, becomes the current Img. The problem is when the site is loaded i can not get a starting img there. That is when im using PHP. It works fine with html.

Comment: Improved formatting, text errors and title